# Something like an If statement

Tags: css

In CSS, I want something like:

```
:root{  
    underline-all-h1-tags:true  
}  
/* it's not all h1 tags, it's actually h1-tags-with-a-bunch-of-other-things".
But for KISS reasons, we'll assume it's just all of them.*/

/* ... lots and lots of other stuff...*/

h1{  
    if(underline-all-h1-tags == true){ 
        text-decoration: underline  
    } else {
        text-decoration:none  
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I know I could just do

```
:root{h1-underline:underline}  
h1{text-decoration:var(h1-underline)}
```

But I am trying to make my code readable to me-in-10-years-when-I-have-totally-forgotten-how-to-CSS.

Comment: you can use the class tag on HTML elements and then use javascript or jquery to edit the value of the class depending on some condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not make use of the cascading part of cascading style sheet?

```
h1{
    text-decoration:none;
}

.underline h1{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Applying the class "underline" to any parent element would do the same thing that it looks like you're trying to describe above.

You could add or remove the underline class with js, or set it statically on elements you want affected.

Comment: I don't think `.underline h1` is a very sensible selector. It's also misleading because the `<div class="underline">` will look silly when people see the whole div isn't underlined.  [read this](http://csswizardry.com/2012/07/shoot-to-kill-css-selector-intent/)

Comment: @chharvey - You're welcome to post a more "sensible" selector. Aside code not particularly being written for people to decide whether or not it is logical while viewing source, it is logical if it achieves what the author is expecting, factoring in their own methods and expectations for maintainability. `h1.underline` is just as functional and would do the same thing. You want to see silly? View source on any drupal site. Used by millions. Looks like crap. Works.

Comment: see my answer for a solution that is much more scalable. I agree with you that `h1.underline` would be a good solution, but simply `.underline` is the best (in my opinion) because you can use it on any element you want, even paragraphs. Either way, `.underline h1` is inefficient with regards to browser processing and nonsensical with regards to human processing.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Kai's answer:

```
h1 { text-decoration: none; }
.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
```

`.underline` is a utility class that can be used to add an underline to any element you want, including an `h1`. This becomes extremely scalable.

Of course I personally wouldn't name it `.underline`; I would probably name it something like
`.u-td_u` (which stands for "utility, text-decoration, underline"). The naming is your choice.

And just for kicks you could also have the other utilities available:

```
.u-td_n { text-decoration: none; }
.u-td_i { text-decoration: inherit; }
.u-td_o { text-decoration: overline; }
.u-td_l { text-decoration: line-through; }
/* etc ... */
```